# I have this problem when i tried to sudo apt update, i cant solve it pls help me!

Tags: updates, repository

N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://mirror.ps.kz/ubuntu disco-backports Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://mirror.ps.kz/ubuntu disco-security Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Comment: Ubuntu 19.04 is EOL or *end-of-life* (http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/01/23/ubuntu-19-04-disco-dingo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-23-2020/) thus off-topic on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) unless your question is specific to help moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Use a LTS or *long-term-support* release if you don't like *release-upgrading* every 6-9 months.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: Your issue is 'disco' (19.04) is EOL.  After a release goes EOL, mirrors can drop it, and the main archive.ubuntu.com gets moved to old-releases.  Refer to prior comment and EOLUpgrades link, or https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release

Comment: To upgrade to new version of Ubuntu, type `sudo do-release-upgrade`, and then "yes" when asked. This may take an hour or two depending on your hardware and internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

To upgrade to new version of Ubuntu, type sudo do-release-upgrade, and then "yes" when asked. This may take an hour or two depending on your hardware and internet connection. – Johannes Lemonde  thanks Johannes Lemonade it helped for me